# DB2 v8 insert with CTE

Tags: db2, expression

I need to select from a CTE (common table expression) in DB2 v8 and insert the result into a table.
The relevant documentation for v8 is hard to understand at first glance, but for v9 there's a clear example (http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db29.doc.apsg/db2z_createcte.htm):

```
INSERT INTO vital_mgr (mgrno)
WITH VITALDEPT (deptno, se_count)  AS
(
     SELECT deptno, count(*)
     FROM DSN8910.EMP
     WHERE job = 'senior engineer'
     GROUP BY deptno
)
SELECT    d.manager
FROM      DSN8910.DEPT d
         , VITALDEPT s
WHERE     d.deptno = s.deptno
          AND s.se_count  >  (
               SELECT  AVG(se_count)
               FROM    VITALDEPT
          );
```

It does not work in v8 though.
How should it be written in v8?

Comment: CTEs are supported in in v8, and the [v8 INSERT documentation](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v8/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.udb.doc/admin/r0000970.htm) matches the format of the query you posted.  You don't mention an error message--are you sure your CTE & subsequent SELECT actually returns any data?

Comment: What platform are you running DB2 on?

Comment: Sorry guys, I did not see your comments, assumed there was no answer.
Turned out we were not going to support v8 anyway but if memory serves I came to the conclusion that INSERT just did not work with CTE in v8.

Answer (score 0):

Write it like a boss

```
INSERT INTO vital_mgr 
(
    SELECT d.manager
    FROM SN8910.DEPT AS d
        INNER JOIN 
            (
                SELECT deptno, count(*)
                FROM DSN8910.EMP
                WHERE job = 'senior engineer'
                GROUP BY deptno
            ) AS s (deptno, se_count)
                ON d.deptno = s.deptno
    WHERE s.se_count > (
                            SELECT AVG(se_count)
                            FROM
                                (
                                    SELECT deptno, count(*)
                                    FROM DSN8910.EMP
                                    WHERE job = 'senior engineer'
                                    GROUP BY deptno
                                ) AS VITALDEPT (deptno, se_count)
                       )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a simple workaround [here](https://groups.google.com/group/comp.databases.ibm-db2/browse_thread/thread/105694324f276587?hl=en) that allows you to use an INSERT or UPDATE using a conventional WITH statement. This hack will work for INSERT on V8 or greater, and for UPDATE on V9 or greater.

There are other methods for V8 or greater, typically using sub-selects, but I find them to be unpractical due to their complexity.