# Insert into using with

Tags: sql, db2, with-statement, insert-into

Is there any way to insert into some table like this:

```
with table_name as (
  ...
)
insert into table1
from table_name
```

I know this way doesn't work, db2 won't allow it, but is there some other way that allows you to insert rows into some table using some other "virtual" table you created, like I did here?

Comment: Nope, no answer for my question there.

Comment: Then what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to insert into new table some elements, but it is very hard to find those elements using syntax: insert into table table_name select... It is much easier to insert it from some call it 'virtual table' I created using "WITH".

Comment: What version are you running? Here's a better duplicate question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3681833/db2-v8-insert-with-cte

Comment: v10, yeah I read the other topic, so basically there is no other way. Thanks for answer.